# Que veut dire « net de tous frais » dans le cas d'une indemnisation ?

Tags: expressions, économie

> L'indemnisation XXX € est nette de tous frais.

Je voudrais savoir que ça veut dire "net de tous frais". Dans le contexte, vais je recevoir XXX € ou (XXX-frais) € ?

### Update

C'est dans le cas d'un retrait obligatoire dans la foulée d’un offre publique d'achat (OPA). Au final, dans mon cas, c'est bien XXX€ sans frais supplémentaire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> L'indemnisation XXX € est nette de tous frais.

Le contexte de cette phrase est important pour en saisir le sens. D'une manière générale, cela veut dire qu'il y avait à l'origine une somme d'indemnisation brute. On déduit les frais de cette somme brute pour arriver à une somme d'indemnisation nette. Soit net = brut - frais.

Si la somme XXX est annoncée en net, on reçoit bien cette somme XXX et pas de frais en plus.
Par contre selon le type d'indemnisation, et le pays, cette somme reçue peut être soumise à imposition.

On peut également trouver l'expression "net d'impôts" concernant une somme, le même raisonnement s'applique : net = brut - impôts. On reçoit la somme annoncée en net.

Par exemple :

- l'indemnité bris de glace d'une assurance voiture : 200€, Franchise : 120€.
  traduction : la somme de l'indemnité est annoncée en brut puisqu'il existe une franchise à appliquer. La somme perçue sera donc 200 - 120 = 80 €.
  La somme de 80€ est alors nette de frais, et n'est pas soumise à imposition en France (sauf erreur de ma part).
- Autre assurance voiture : Bris de glace 120€, Franchise 0€. Vous recevez bien la somme de 120€ (sauf annotations supplémentaire dans le contrat)
- je prends l'exemple des salaires même s'il ne s'agit pas d'une indemnité parce que le principe est fondamentalement le même : En France, les salaires sont annoncés en brut. Il faut y retrancher toutes les cotisations (charges sociales et autres...) qui peuvent se comprendre comme des frais. Vous recevez ensuite une somme nette de cotisations/frais. Il vous faut ensuite déclarer la totalité des sommes reçues qui sont soumises à imposition. Vous pouvez à ce moment là déclarer des éventuels frais professionnels qui seront déduits et permettront de baisser l'impôt.

Pourquoi le contexte de cette phrase est important ? Parce que dans le cas d'un contrat entre deux personnes, cette clause ne peut être opposée à l'administration.

Par exemple :

- Dans le cadre d'un testament, on peut trouver l'expression "net de tous les frais et droits de succession". Il est possible qu’une personne X soit libre de tout frais, pourvu qu’une personne Y accepte de prendre les frais de la succession à sa charge. S'il n'existe que la personne X, alors elle aura les frais à prendre en charge même si la somme est annoncée nette de tous frais dans le testament.

Si vous m'avez suivie, outre la langue, cette expression concerne le droit et l'économie. C'est bien le contexte de cette phrase qui permettra d'en comprendre le sens et déterminer si c'est avec ou sans frais au final.